# i can't found where the picasso save the image in sd card

Tags: android, path, sd-card, picasso

i use **Picasso** to download image and show them in my **Android** app, it work correctly. now i want to download all image in first page and show them in second one. the question is, where the image will be save? i need the **path** to download image there.
is there any way to access the **path** or **change** it?

Comment: I believe Picasso caches the images in the Environment.getCache() dir

Comment: If you run your application on an emulator and use ddms to browse the data.data folder of your app you should see where the images are being cached

Comment: Isn't it possible to use picasso with the same urls in the second page again? Picasso will not download them again but get them from the cache. Well that's what i think.

Comment: Picasso used LruCache instance as cache so there is no path to images - the images are kept in memory

Answer (score 0):

You can download your images using their urrls to desired path on internal storage and then load them into your image view simply by using this two methods:

```
public void downloadImagesToSdCard(String downloadUrl, String imageName)
 //downloadURL is the url of your image and imageName is the name you choose for your image file on internal storage

{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);
                    /* making a directory in sdcard */
        String sdCard= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(sdCard,"Your Arbitrary Folder Name");

                    /*  if specified not exist create new */
        if(!myDir.exists())
        {
            myDir.mkdir();
            Log.v("", "inside mkdir");
        }

                    /* checks the file and if it already exist delete */
        String fname = imageName;
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ())
            file.delete ();

                         /* Open a connection */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)ucon;
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int totalSize = httpConn.getContentLength();
        int downloadedSize = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 )
        {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
        }

        fos.close();
        Log.d("test", "Image Saved in sdcard..");
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

After using the above method, your image downloaded from input url to specified folder and image name(imageName) in internal storage of your device. Then you should load image from this path to ImageView. You can use below method to do this:

```
public Bitmap loadToImageView(ImageView myImage, String sd_address) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        //File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Your Arbitary Folder  Name/matin.jpg");
        File imgFile = new File(sd_address);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            //ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
        return myBitmap;
    }
```

Thus, your image is loading from specified sd_address to imageview using setImageBitmap method. I hope this help you! :)